# Unity3D Detecting the Edge of the Screen - Object is Flickering when moved

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi am developing a simple Space Shooter styled 2D game and I am stuck at the point where the Object should restrict itself moving beyond the left and right edges of the screen.

I implemented @Waz solution in one of the answers in Unity Answers and it works great if the object is not a rigidbody. However if it is applied to a rigidbody, the object starts to flicker. Below is the code that I used from @Waz

```
    float speed = 0.1f;
    Vector3 viewPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);
    viewPos.x = Mathf.Clamp01(viewPos.x);
    viewPos.y = Mathf.Clamp01(viewPos.y);
    transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(viewPos);
```

Here is the link where @Waz mentioned his piece of code:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/148790/detecting-the-edge-of-the-screen.html

Here is a link that says to use an alternative solution for rigidbody but this code does not work for me:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/62189/detect-edge-of-screen.html

I am not sure how to modify the above code so that the object I touch and move does not flicker. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are translating from arbitrary float coordinates to the range [0,1] and back again.  Likely the issue you are running into is due to floating-point inaccuracies when your world-position is far away from 0.

There are multiple ways of solving this:

1. In your above script, only perform the transform if they are actually touching the edge of the screen.
2. Handle the [`OnBecameVisible()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html) and [`OnBecameInvisible()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html) messages.  Don't let the player move off screen if it would cause them to "go invisible".
3. Use the `IsVisibleFrom()` callback from [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=IsVisibleFrom) wiki article.  [Some people](http://pixelnest.io/tutorials/2d-game-unity/parallax-scrolling/) prefer this because they claim that *"`OnBecameVisible()`/`OnBecameInvisible()` are broken."*
   I don't know how/why they believe they're broken.

Comment: Thank You, I got a suggestion from another post asking me to use FixedUpdate instead of Update and this fixed the flickering. Is it a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Screen.width and Screen.height in detecting the edge of the screen? Maybe it can help in the prevention of the flickering.

Comment: Yes I did, this did not be of much help to me. The screen width and height solution works fine for Web and PC but not for Android.
The flickering issue is fixed now with the same code moved from Update to the FixedUpdate method

Comment: I can have another solution where I can place two invisible objects with colliders at both the corners of the screen. So, when my space ship hits these corners, these objects will block the ship going out of the screen. But I am not sure if this solution is worthy.

Comment: But at least the flickering issue is fixed now. Um, I'm still researching about the way to get screen dimensions on Android devices with Unity and if it seems a more worthy solution I'll relay them to you. By the way, what if you just set the dimensions in your codes? That way you can easily get the edges... oh, but then the game output will have black spaces if the device has greater resolution.

Comment: Right, I tried setting the dimensions as well but this does not work properly on different resolutions.

Comment: I got a very easy solution for this, thanks to Unity3Dstudent.com
http://www.unity3dstudent.com/2010/11/beginner-b26-using-mathf-clamp-to-restrict-values/
This is for C#:

    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -110, 10), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

Comment: Thanks for sharing @SriramKumar :D I might need these codes in my next project. Happy coding to us!